# Aircrack -ng not working

Tags: kali-linux, aircrack-ng

```
root@kali:~# aircrack-ng –a2 –b F8:1A:67:56:52:36 –w /root/pass.txt /root/Desktop/*.cap
Opening –a2
open failed: No such file or directory
Opening –b
open failed: No such file or directory
Opening F8:1A:67:56:52:36
open failed: No such file or directory
Opening –w
open failed: No such file or directory
Opening /root/pass.txt
Unsupported file format (not a pcap or IVs file).
Opening /root/Desktop/-01.cap
Read 219544 packets.
# BSSID ESSID Encryption
1 F8:1A:67:56:52:36 khushi sahu WPA (1 handshake)
Choosing first network as target. root@kali:~#
```

Why is it showing `-a2, -b, -w` as `"open failed: No such file or directory"`, although they are aircrack commands?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your "minuses" appear to be "en dashes" rather than ASCII hyphens

Answer (score 2):

From the Aircrack-ng website: https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=aircrack-ng

`aircrack-ng -w password.lst *.cap`

Where:

-w password.lst is the name of the password file. Remember to specify the full path if the file is not located in the same directory.
*.cap is name of group of files containing the captured packets. Notice in this case that we used the wildcard * to include multiple files.

It appears you are feeding aircrack an invalid dictionary file. Aircrack-ng is a bruteforce tool so you need a dictionary to crack your cap file or a generator such as  john-the-ripper. If that is the name of your password dictionary then make sure you are including the correct path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove -a2 in order use it properly